# Choosing k points with the minimum possible diameter

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, computational-geometry

Given a set of `n` points and an `n x n` distance matrix, how do I pick exactly `k` of these points such that the diameter (maximum distance between any two chosen points) is minimized? The distance metric obeys the triangle inequality but is not necessarily euclidean or minkowski distance. We can assume all distances are pairwise distinct.

Additionally, I would like to solve this problem for all k in the range `n - 1, n - 2, ... n - d`. I know this can be done much quicker than just checking all `n choose k` combinations for each `k`, but the solutions I have come up with are still not very efficient (I am pretty sure a polynomial-time solution does not exist but I'm wondering if it is possible to do better).

The only method I have come up is a recursive one. Find the two points `p1` and `p2` with the largest distance between them (sort all pairs by distance first). Then the `k = n - 1` case is one of the sets consisting of all points minus either p1 or p2. One may be better than another or it may be a tie. All solutions for `k < n - 1` must necessarily be a subset of one of these sets (cannot contain both p1 and p2), but not necessarily the winning one. Continue checking subsets of these two sets. I think this is something like `O(n^2 log n + 2^d)`, but that's still better than checking all combinations for each `k` down to `n - d` as long as `d` is small enough (I think at least to `k / 2`).

A related problem - find the largest subset with diameter no larger than `t` - is equivalent to the [independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) (take the graph with edges where distances are larger than `t`) but this known to be NP-hard.

None of these solutions make use of the triangle inequality, which leaves me a small amount of hope that a more efficient solution does exist.

Answer (score 0):

A metric which obeys the triangle inequality should be able to support a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree. This will save time in searches for close points if in practice the metric is roughly the same as a low-dimensional space.

Given this, I would run a branch and bound search, recursively searching all (n choose k) possibilities, but discarding partial solutions as soon as possible, by reversibly deleting sub-trees from the cover tree. At each stage of the search you have a distance corresponding to the best answer found so far (at the beginning this could be infinity, or a guess). When you add a point to the current partial solution, you can reversibly delete from the cover tree subtrees which contain only points which are at a distance greater than or equal to the current best distance from the point you have just added. With a cover tree, you can check for this using a deduction from the triangle inequality: d(a, b) + d(b, c) >= d(a,c) implies d(a, b) >= d(a, c) - d(b,c). If you find there aren't enough points in the remaining cover tree to complete the current partial solution, you can return from that section of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

For all Ds that are comparable with all of your distances:

Consider the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) whose set of vertices is your set of points and whose edges

are the pairs {p,q} such that the distance between those points is *greater* than D.

A set of points has diameter at most D if and only if its complement is a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Thus your problem is NP-hard but becomes

fixed-parameter tractable when parameterized by ​ n-k :

Use binary search with [this algorithm](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/research/TechReports/TR05-008.pdf) to determine the lowest

gap-between-distances that D can be in and what missing points achieve that gap.